# How to mutate based on condition using case_when using R

Tags: r, case

I’m struggling to find a way to create a new variable based on conditions. In this case I want to create a variable called “size” based on the variable called “number”, but the rules for “size” is different depending on the variable called “type”. So when "number" is 1 then one set of case_when rules should apply, when "number" is 2 another set of case_whn rules should apply.

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Create data
dat <- tribble(
  ~number, ~type,
   232,      1,
   383,      2,
   832,      1,
   722,      2,
   134,      1,
   211,      2,
   970,      1
)

# This works

dat |> mutate(size = case_when(
  number > 400 ~ "big",
  number < 400 ~ "medium",
  number < 200 ~ "small"
))

# This also works

dat |> mutate(size = case_when(
  number > 700 ~ "super big",
  between(number, 400, 700) ~ "quite medium",
  number < 400 ~ "quite small"
))

# I would like do this, but it doesn't work
dat %>% 
  if (type == 1) {
    mutate(size = case_when(
      number > 400 ~ "big",
      number < 400 ~ "medium",
      number < 200 ~ "small"
    ))
  } else {
    mutate(size = case_when(
      number > 700 ~ "super big",
      between(number, 400, 700) ~ "quite medium",
      number < 400 ~ "quite small"
    ))
  }
```

The expected result should be like this:

```
number  type size
232     1    medium
383     2    quite small
832     1    big
722     2    super big
134     1    medium
211     2    quite small
970     1    big
```

Comment: Check the solution with `case_match`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could directly use `case_match`:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(size = case_match(type,
    1 ~ case_when(
                    number > 400 ~ "big",
                    number < 400 ~ "medium",
                    number < 200 ~ "small"),
    2 ~ case_when(
                    number > 700 ~ "super big",
                    between(number, 400, 700) ~ "quite medium",
                    number < 400 ~ "quite small")))

# A tibble: 7 × 3
  number  type size       
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
1    232     1 medium     
2    383     2 quite small
3    832     1 big        
4    722     2 super big  
5    134     1 medium     
6    211     2 quite small
7    970     1 big
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this give you what you want?

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(
    size = ifelse(
      type == 1,
      case_when(
        number > 400 ~ "big",
        number < 400 ~ "medium",
        number < 200 ~ "small"
      ),
      NA
    ),
    impression = ifelse(
      type == 1,
      NA,
      case_when(
        number > 700 ~ "super big",
        between(number, 400, 700) ~ "quite medium",
        number < 400 ~ "quite small"
      )
    )
  )
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  number  type size   impression 
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      
1    232     1 medium NA         
2    383     2 NA     quite small
3    832     1 big    NA         
4    722     2 NA     super big  
5    134     1 medium NA         
6    211     2 NA     quite small
7    970     1 big    NA
```

Essentially, using `ifelse` rather than `if ... else` and placing it *inside* rather than *outside* the `mutate` call.

**EDIT**

OK, from your comments, it looks as if you want the texts corresponding to `type == 1` and `type == 2` in the same column rather than different ones.  Correct?

If so, that's actually easier, because it removes one step in the logic.

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(
    size = ifelse(
      type == 1,
      case_when(
        number > 400 ~ "big",
        number < 400 ~ "medium",
        number < 200 ~ "small"
      ),
      case_when(
        number > 700 ~ "super big",
        between(number, 400, 700) ~ "quite medium",
        number < 400 ~ "quite small"
      )
    )
  )
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  number  type size       
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
1    232     1 medium     
2    383     2 quite small
3    832     1 big        
4    722     2 super big  
5    134     1 medium     
6    211     2 quite small
7    970     1 big
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Limey! Your answered right but I just realized that my question whasn't clear. If "number" variable == 2 the new the case_when should create "size" variable based on the second case_when rule. like this

 # I would like do this, but it doesn't work
dat %>% 
  if (type == 1) {
    mutate(size = case_when(
      number > 400 ~ "big",
      number < 400 ~ "medium",
      number < 200 ~ "small"
    ))
  } else {
    mutate(size = case_when(
      number > 700 ~ "super big",
      between(number, 400, 700) ~ "quite medium",
      number < 400 ~ "quite small"
    ))
  }

Comment: Please amend your question to include the expected output based on your test data.  I will edit my answer once you have done so.  [Providing code that "doesn't work" without explicitly providing exact details of your desired output is not helpful!]

Comment: number type  size
232 1 medium
383 2 quite small
832 1 big
722 2 super big
134 1 medium
211 2 quite small
970 1 big

Comment: No.  Please edit your *question* rather than posting additional information as a comment.  The comment is harder to understand and is less clear to future readers.

Comment: Of course (I'm not used to Stackoverflow). Got "There are too many pending edits"...Please try again later. So I will try in a while. But I'm vefy grateful for your help

Comment: I have edited the question now, and privided a expected result. Sorry for my badly formulated question

Comment: Yes! That's just right! Thanks so much @limey